# Determine vector components based on vector scaling and change of origin

Tags: robotics

Consider a known vector *k* and an unknown vector *L*. *L* is positioned between vector *k* and an unknown fixed point in space. The vector *L* is comprised of two components, but is subject to change over time, hence a scaling factor *delta(t)*.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X1yXt.png)

I would like to determine the vector components of *L*, such that *w* can be determined.

I am able to translate and rotate the coordinate origin and sample the data of *x(t), y(t), and theta(t)*, while also sampling the change of vector *L* collected in *delta(t)*.

I am figuring that a least-square optimisation is needed to determine *L*'s components, where an error based on the sampling data is minimised. However, so far I have been unable to setup the scheme.

Thanks.

Comment: In the linked figure, what are the symbols, whose values are known ? $\vec{k}$, $\theta(t)$?, $x(t)$?, $y(t)$? Since $\delta(t)$ is multiplying $[u, v]$, does that mean the change in $L = [u, v]$ is always along itself ?

Comment: @AJN k is a known constant vector. theta(t), x(t), y(t) and delta(t) are data which are sampled over time. You are correct in the your understanding of L. delta(t) will produce scalar values, and as such, just "change L along itself", i.e. increasing or decreasing the length of the L vector.

Comment: Please include your image in your question. When you [edit] it like this, people can have all of the information at once without looking somewhere else.